# Implied Status in Canada

Tags: canada, paperwork

I am almost at the end of my 2-year International Experience Canada (IEC) work permit. I have applied for a change to Visitor Status so that I can stay in Canada a while longer. If my IEC work permit expires before I get a response then I think that I will have Implied Status. While having Implied Status, will I be allowed to continue working under the terms of my expired IEC work permit?

Comment: Quoting from [CIC](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=474&top=17) `If you applied for another work permit:
You must stay in Canada and meet the conditions of your original work permit. If you applied for a work permit extension before your work permit expired, you can keep working under the same conditions as your existing permit until CIC decides on your application, even if you have applied to extend your stay under another category of temporary resident.`(1/2)

Comment: `If you applied for a different kind of permit: You cannot do any of the activities allowed by the original work permit. For example, you may have come to Canada as a worker and then applied for a study permit. If so, you must stop working once your work permit expires. After that, you cannot work or study until you get a new permit.` It seems you can work until you get your new visitor permit. After that your status changes to visitor so you can't work after that. But until then you should be fine. (2/2)

Comment: @DipenShah  OP is switching from a permit that permits work to one that doesn't. To me, that implies that the 2nd case is true--he needs to stop working when the IEC/work permit expires.

Comment: @mkennedy That is correct. The first one is only valid for work permit extensions.

Comment: @DipenShah why not post that as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [CIC](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=474&top=17)

> - **If you applied for another work permit:**
>
> **You must stay in Canada and meet the conditions of your original work
>   permit.** If you applied for a work permit extension before your work
>   permit expired, you can keep working under the same conditions as your
>   existing permit until CIC decides on your application, even if you
>   have applied to extend your stay under another category of temporary
>   resident.
>
> - **If you applied for a different kind of permit:**
>
> **You cannot do any of the activities allowed by the original work
>   permit.** For example, you may have come to Canada as a worker and then
>   applied for a study permit. If so, you must stop working once your
>   work permit expires. After that, you cannot work or study until you
>   get a new permit.

The second part is related to your case I think which basically breaks down to this:

You can work until your work permit expires or you get the visitor permit. After that your status changes to visitor so you can't work after that. Until then you are allowed to do all the activities that are allowed in your original work permit.

Comment: I still feel that you're giving the wrong answer. If the OP's work permit expires before he gets the visitor permit, he cannot work any more because the new permit is not in the same category (allowing work).

Comment: Sorry maybe my words are misunderstood but I'm trying to convey the same thing as you are saying and not disagreeing with you. I'll rephrase my answer maybe tomorrow to make more sense to it.

Comment: Thanks! My problem is specifically with "You can work until you get your new visitor permit." Maybe just change it to, "You can work until your work permit expires or you get the visitor permit." He will not have "implied status" because he hasn't applied for another temporary resident visa.

Comment: @mkennedy You are right. That does make more sense. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.